# Is there a way to get the command ran to get stdin output in python?

Tags: python, linux, stdin

So I've found a way to read from stdin in python, which is as follows:

```py
if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    stdin = sys.stdin.read()
```

but for a statement like this,

```bash
echo Hello | program.py
```

I only get stdin = Hello, which is how it should work.
My question is, is there a way to get the whole command as a string in the python program,
for example, getting "echo Hello" in the previous exmaple?

Any alternative to get the command in program.py will work too.
Thanks :)

Haven't got a good idea yet, so have not tried anything as of yet.

Comment: Can't you just do `echo "echo 'Hello'" | program.py`?

Comment: That was just an example, I want both the command and its output, echo Hello and hello in seperate strings

Comment: You can call external programs within Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/89243/1867662. So one way you could achieve what you want is to input the entire command, and then run it using subprocess.run.

Comment: Note, that `echo Hello` likely _finishes_ before program.py has a chance to run, because pipe buffering. The information that `echo Hello` has existed may just no longer be there at all at the time program.py runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not.
You could think of launching a program as creating a box with 2 tubes, stdin and stdout (and stderr but nvm).

With `echo Hello | program.py` your creating 2 boxes, one for `echo` and one for  `python`, then with `|` you pipe echo's stdout to python's stdin.

You could launch python first, then execute `echo Hello`, however you would need to modify your python script first to wait for inputs on stdin, then to pass the inputs to a shell subprocess's stdin, read that subprocess stdout and return that to you through it's own stdout.